# Can I store an array within a multidimensional array? (PHP)

Tags: php, json

It is possible to put an array into a multi dim array? I have a list of user settings that I want to return in a JSON array and also have another array stored in that JSON array...what is the best way to do that if it isn't possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi dimension is already an array inside an array. So there's nothing stopping you from putting another array in there. Sort of like dreams within dreams :P

Just use associative arrays if you want to give your array meaning

```
array(
   'SETTINGS' => array(
      'arr1' => array( 0, 1),
      'arr2' => array( 0, 1)  
   ),
   'DATA' => array(
      'arr1' => array( 0, 1),
      'arr2' => array( 0, 1)  
    )
)
```

**EDIT**

To answer your comment, `$output_files[$file_id]['shared_with'] = $shared_info;` translates to (your comment had an extra `]` which I removed)

```
$shared_info = array(1, 2, 3);
$file_id     = 3;
$output_files = array(
  '3' => array(
     'shared_with' => array() //this is where $shared_info will get assigned
   )
);
//you don't actually have to declare it an empty array. I just did it to demonstrate.
$output_files[$file_id]['shared_with'] = $shared_info; // now that empty array is replaced.
```

Comment: I am trying to put the array $shared_info as the value for "shared_with" with the file_id as the "key" i think it's called? sorry i'm new:)

$output_files[$file_id]]['shared_with'] = $shared_info;

Comment: Worth adding that you can access the above array by calling something like:
`$yourarray['SETTINGS']['arr1'][1]`

Comment: @Matthew Berman Edited the question to show how your array actually looks. You're on the right path. @soulkphp indeed, to any (sensible) depth :)

Comment: well I have it just like that but when i print_r it...the array within the array just prints as "array" and doesn't show the values...

here is what the array plus first item of the array printout looks like when i do print_r($output_files);

Array ( [2043] => Array ( [shared_with] => Array

)

Comment: @Matthew Berman could you post your code in your question? You might have to modify the relevant bit so we can replicate it

Answer (score 0):

any array key can have an array value in php, as well as in json.

php:

```
'key' => array(...)
```

json:

```
"key" : [...]
```

note: php doesn't support multidimensional arrays as in C or C++. it's just an array element containing another array.